# Set environment variable in RUN section Dockerfile

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile

I want to create an image , with git pre-installed **that can log in Github during docker-run**.

This image suppose to get Github username and token in `docker-run` command through `-e` **option**.

For example :

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -e "username=parsalotfy" -e "token=secretsecretsecret" -e "email=parsalotfy@gmail.com" gitloggedin
```

I wrote Dockerfile like this :

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add git
RUN git clone https://$username:$token@github.com/$username/$repo.git
RUN cd $repo/
RUN git config user.email $email

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

But when I want to **build** this Dockerfile, this error occurs :

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

And How can I have a Github user logged in passing username and password through `-e` option after `docker-run` ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica with ENV there is a default value !

Comment: Are you willing to use `DOCKER_BUILDKIT`?

Comment: Inside the `Dockerfile` none of those variables are defined; the `docker build` command doesn't know what arguments the `docker run` will eventually be invoked with.  For a couple of reasons I'd suggest checking out the source tree you're trying to build outside of the `Dockerfile`, and picking a specific filesystem path inside the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone mentioned the reference link in comments you'll need to declare your environment variables before use like `ENV EMAIL me@example.com` or just `ENV EMAIL` then using it